# Calling function in mustache Javascript to process a list and generate a list

Tags: javascript, html, mustache, processlist

In mustache I know how to write a function with arguments but I want to process a list of data through a function.
So, my JSON data from an API call is as follows:

`result = [{email: ‘xyz@test.com’, score1: 2, score2: 3},
          {email: ‘abc@test.com’, score1: 5, score2: 3},
          {email: ‘dummy@test.com’, score1: 2, score2: 0}
    ]`

Now, I actually want to repeat an image in html for the number stated in score1 and score2.
So, in html I want to have 2 images of stars and 3 images of flames for 1st entry. Similarly, for the consecutive elements in the list.

The other way would be to iterate though the list and then assign a variable to be [1,2] in mustache. But, I want to avoid iterating as there would be too many records.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: jQuery.parseJSON() might come in handy here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, I want a pure JavaScript Solution.

Comment: You could use CSS classes for this?